# flex box container border-radius

Tags: html, css

I've got one problem. My HTML looks currently like this:
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 
 
     <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./assets/images/favicon-32x32.png">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
     <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
     <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 
     <title>Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <main>
         <section class="area-1">
             <h2 class="h1">Join our community</h2>
            <p class="subh">30-day, hassle-free money back gurantee</span></p>
             <p class="p1">Gain access to our full library of tutorials along with expert code reviews.
 Perfect for any developers who are serious about honing their skills.</p>
         </section>
         <section class="area-2">
             <h2 class="h2">Monthly Subscription</h2>
             <div class="para-grid">
                 <p class="p2">&dollar;29</p>
                 <p class="p2-1">per month</p>
             </div>
             <p class="p2-2">Full access for less than &dollar;1 a day</p>
             <div class="button">
                 <p>Sign Up</p>
             </div>
         </section>
         <section class="area-3">
             <h2 class="h3">Why us</h2>
             <p class="p3">Tutorials by industry experts</p>
             <p class="p3">Peer &amp; expert code review</p>
             <p class="p3">Coding exercises</p>
             <p class="p3">Access to our GitHub repos</p>
             <p class="p3">Community forum</p>
             <p class="p3">Flashcard decks</p>
             <p class="p3">New videos every week</p>
         </section>
     </main>
</body>
</html>
```

And now I made my `main` into a `flex-item` by writing down my `body` with:

```
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2rem;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

and now my `main` is in the middle horizontally & vertically but I've got one problem. I want to make my main part to be rounded with `border-radius: 10px` which should make my flex-item look like this in the corners
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udiZT.jpg)

but it does not work if I do it. Here is a current code of my CSS & an example how it looks as image
CSS

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

:root {
    /* COLORS FOR THE AREAS */
    --color-area1: hsl(204, 43%, 93%);
    --color-area2: hsl(179, 62%, 43%);
    --color-area3: hsl(179, 63%, 47%);
    --color-button: hsl(71, 73%, 54%);
    /* COLORS FOR THE TEXT */
    --color-h1: hsl(179, 62%, 43%);
    --color-subh: hsl(71, 85%, 48%);
    --color-p1: hsl(218, 22%, 67%);
}

html {
    font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2rem;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

main {
    max-width: 20rem;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.2);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* styling the areas*/

section {
    padding: 1.5rem;
}

.area-2 {
    background: var(--color-area2);
}

.area-3 {
    background: var(--color-area3);
}
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ELue.png)

Somehow only my upper corner of my `main` is rounded but somehow I have to give my `area-3` an extra `border-radius` that the bottom side of my `main` is as well rounded. Does someone know why it is like that? because normally my `flex-item` `main` should be responsive and as `width & height` as the children's inside my parent `main`

Maybe it is because of `flex-box`? I am clueless why it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main element's background isn't extending to cover the whole rounded area due to the `padding` applied to the section elements. To achieve the desired rounded effect for the entire main element, you should apply the `border-radius` property directly to the main element and set its `overflow` property to `hidden`.

```
main {
    max-width: 20rem;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.2);
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden; /* This line should fix things */
}
```

Here's my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9gmwL7rb/) showing the behavior you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can add border-radius to **upper** part of `.area-1` and **bottom** part of `.area-3` separately.

`border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;`
(Add this code to .area-1 class)

`border-radius:  0 0 10px 10px;`
(Add this code to .area-3 class)

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
}

:root {
/* COLORS FOR THE AREAS */
--color-area1: hsl(204, 43%, 93%);
--color-area2: hsl(179, 62%, 43%);
--color-area3: hsl(179, 63%, 47%);
--color-button: hsl(71, 73%, 54%);
/* COLORS FOR THE TEXT */
--color-h1: hsl(179, 62%, 43%);
--color-subh: hsl(71, 85%, 48%);
--color-p1: hsl(218, 22%, 67%);
}

html {
font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
}

body {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
padding: 2rem;
min-height: 100vh;
}

main {
max-width: 20rem;
box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.2);
border-radius: 10px;
}

/* styling the areas*/

section {
padding: 1.5rem;
}
.area-1 {
border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
.area-2 {
background: var(--color-area2);
}

.area-3 {
background: var(--color-area3);
border-radius:  0 0 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./assets/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<main>
<section class="area-1">
<h2 class="h1">Join our community</h2>
<p class="subh">30-day, hassle-free money back gurantee</span></p>
<p class="p1">Gain access to our full library of tutorials along with expert code reviews.
Perfect for any developers who are serious about honing their skills.</p>
</section>
<section class="area-2">
<h2 class="h2">Monthly Subscription</h2>
<div class="para-grid">
<p class="p2">&dollar;29</p>
<p class="p2-1">per month</p>
</div>
<p class="p2-2">Full access for less than &dollar;1 a day</p>
<div class="button">
<p>Sign Up</p>
</div>
</section>
<section class="area-3">
<h2 class="h3">Why us</h2>
<p class="p3">Tutorials by industry experts</p>
<p class="p3">Peer &amp; expert code review</p>
<p class="p3">Coding exercises</p>
<p class="p3">Access to our GitHub repos</p>
<p class="p3">Community forum</p>
<p class="p3">Flashcard decks</p>
<p class="p3">New videos every week</p>
</section>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```